# Possible to edit a collection in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to change a maintenance plan in SSIS to dynamically backup certain databases to certain places based on certain conditions... But it looks like the maintenance tasks use a collection for the selected databases list.  As far as I can tell, I can't seem to manipulate a collection through an expression, nor can I seem to load up a variable to work as a collection.

Does anyone know a clever work around for this or do I just need to cut my loses and drop down into t-sql for it all?

Comment: Can you change it from a maintenance task to a dataflow task? Write it as a dataflow task seperately, and replace it.

Comment: Not Really. I'm trying to specifically use the maintenance task.  Long story short, I got tired of trying stuff so just dropped out to t-sql task in the package and that accomplished what they were wanting.  I'm still baffled by the SSIS peoples choice to have an unmodifiable collection when everything else in SSIS gives you so much leverage/flexiblity.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS has always been a source of irritation for me.  Personally, I'd write the job up in TSQL, then schedule it using the SQL Server Agent.  It feels lighter weight to me in the sense that if I need to edit the job, all I need to do is open up SQL Management Studio and make the change.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: In summary, you are saying there isn't a way to modify collections right?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't know if it's possible.  I was just offering my thoughts on using SSIS for this type of job in general.